# How i can change and to e in abntex2-alf?

Tags: bibliographies, languages, abntex2

I have some problems with my refs, I want to translate "and" to "e" (end of figure below). For this text I used:

```
\renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Citado na(s) página(s):~}

\renewcommand{\backref}{}

\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
    
\ifcase #1 %
        
Nenhuma citação no texto.%
    
\or
        
Citado na página #2.%
    
\else
        
Citado #1 vezes nas páginas #2.%
    
\fi}%
```

[image]

Comment: You need to provide a complete but minimal working example of what you're trying to do.  This would be a full LaTeX document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` showing which packages you're using and, presumably a `.bib` file as well.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What is `abntex2-alf` -- a document class, a bibliography style, something else? As @DonHosek has noted, to increase the chances that someone will come up with a solution, you need to provide sufficient information to allow a solid diagnosis of what's going on.